# Detecting mouse wheel movement in Flash (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mousewheel

I have a Flash application that have to detect the mouse wheel event (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL), I've tested on a stand alone flash player and works perfect, but when i put the swf in a web browser, the mouse wheel stop working.

I've tested this in: Internet Explorer 7.0, Mozilla Firefox 3, Safari 3 and Google Chrome; and this behavior happens in all of the browsers

PS: The swf file is embed in the body of the page, a simple page with only the swf.

EDIT: The swf has wmode set to opaque and it has focus on it when this bug happens.

Comment: It may help if you post the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your SWF file have focus when you try to scroll? If it does not, the browser window will scroll instead.

Probably related: I found this bug in the Adobe JIRA btw: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-289 This is when the wmode is transparent or opaque. Can you check your html code for this property? Here is a workaround: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=13086